# What value to enter in yahoo finance cost basis

Tags: yahoo-finance, cost-basis

I've just started using yahoo finance. I've only bought shares at atm.

I've added Portfolio->My holdings-> Symbol-> Lot

Under Lot what is the value to enter on Cost basis? Is it share cost per share or it's total cost for all shares?

Comment: Do you also enter a number of shares? If you enter the total cost do you get nonsensical P/L numbers?

Comment: Yes, I've entered total number of shares. Yes I see something weird with total gain values.

Comment: OK so try a per-share price. Do you see correct total gains now?

Comment: Enter your cost per share.  If you enter the cost basis of the entire position, you will have a monstrous gain (or loss  :-)

Comment: Tx Bob, it is indeed cost/share.